# How can i bring this data from DE stored in a text in into table and rows SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, sql

I have this data in Data extension but in a text field. I want to out put this in table format like

Months Amount Rate

[image]

12\x2d17 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.250', '249999.99':'4.250', '999999.99':'4.250', '9999999.99':'4.250'},
'18\x2d18 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.750', '249999.99':'4.750', '999999.99':'4.750', '9999999.99':'4.750'},
'19\x2d23 MTHS' : {'99999.99':'4.750', '249999.99':'4.750', '999999.99':'4.750', '9999999.99':'4.750'},
'24\x2d35 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.700', '249999.99':'4.700', '999999.99':'4.700', '9999999.99':'4.700'},
'36\x2d47 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.500', '249999.99':'4.500', '999999.99':'4.500', '9999999.99':'4.500'},
'48\x2d59 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.450', '249999.99':'4.450', '999999.99':'4.450', '9999999.99':'4.450'},
'60\x2d71 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.500', '249999.99':'4.500', '999999.99':'4.500', '9999999.99':'4.500'},
'72\x2d83 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.600', '249999.99':'4.600', '999999.99':'4.600', '9999999.99':'4.600'},
'84\x2d119 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.700', '249999.99':'4.700', '999999.99':'4.700', '9999999.99':'4.700'},
'120\x2d120 MTH' : {'99999.99':'4.800', '249999.99':'4.800', '999999.99':'4.800', '9999999.99':'4.800'}}

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Comment: First I get the data using the script   <script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1");
var response = HTTP.Get("XXXXXXXXXXXXX);
var rates = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response.Content);

try{
var addedRow = Platform.Function.InsertData(
'Rates',
['Text_json'],
[rates]
);
}
catch(e){
Write("error"+e)
}
</script>

Comment: Than i use SQL to move the data i need in another DE Select SUBSTRING(Text_json, CHARINDEX('var GIC_annual = ', Text_json) + 18,
1270 - CHARINDEX('var GIC_annual = ', Text_json)) as GIC_annual from Rates

Comment: I though it will be a JSON format and i can use SQL JSONNPARSER  or SSJS to parse JSON but it does not work .. I am stuck